# php two dependent dropdowns mysql query fetch to array

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, dropdown

I am currently struggling with two dropdowns where the data from mysql fetches not correcly.

The first dropdown is a list of locations followed by the second dropdown that must show the dates available.

here is the code of the requested php:

```
<?php
require('base.php');
switch(@$_REQUEST['location']){
    case 'RD':
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `courses` where location = 'Dubai'");
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {
        $locdata = array_push($locdata, echo $row['day'].' '.$row['date'].' '.$row['month']);
        }
        break;
    case 'UT': 
        $locdata=array( 'Monday 22 August', 'Tuesday 23 August');
        break;
    case 'NY':
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `cursussen` where locatie = 'New York'");
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {
        $locdata = array_push($locdata, echo $row['dag'].' '.$row['datum'].' '.$row['maand']);
        }
        break;
    case 'AM':
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `cursussen` where locatie = 'Amsterdam'");
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {
        $locdata = array_push($locdata, echo $row['dag'].' '.$row['datum'].' '.$row['maand']);
        }
        break;

    default: 
        $locdata=false;
}
if(!$locdata)echo 'Selecteer eerst een locatie';
else echo '<select name="locations"><option>'.join('</option>           <option>',$locdata).'</select>';
```

If all cases is set manually like in case UT, it works perfectly. How can append the data obtained from the database into an array?

Comment: Stop [suppressing errors](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php), they can help you fix your problems!

Comment: You ***should*** switch from `mysql_*` as it has been [officially](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) deprecated. Use [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) **with** [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Displaying all errors still shows nothing. And using mysql_* does works when I fetch the query into one element ($locdata= array('row['day'].row['month']') into the array but appending (append_push) does not

Comment: You misunderstood my second comment.

Comment: I tried mysqli as well but still

Answer (score 0):

First set up the array before your Switch using:

```
$locdata = array();
```

And then correct your push:

```
array_push($locdata, ..... etc )
```

Comment: How do i put this > $row['dag'].' '.$row['datum'].' '.$row['maand'] into between "" ? it is showing me an error when i try to put that in a string. I tried this as well "$row[\'dag\'].\' \'.$row[\'datum\'].\' \'.$row['\maand\']" (using backslash before ' )

Comment: I think I am facing an syntax error since I dont know how to put the fetched rows values into a string in the correct way

Comment: thanks! correcting my array push after correcting my syntax did the job

Comment: Sorry - didn't check the syntax, but I guess you sorted it. No need for all the quotes and echos. Well done.

Answer (score 0):

```
case 'RD':
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `course` where locatie='Amsterdam'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
    // if (!$result) {
    //   printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
    //   exit();
    //}     
    $locdata = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $temp = $row['day']." ".$row['date']." ".$row['month'];
        array_push($locdata, $temp);
    }
    break;
```

did the job